# Simple Question: split function in python

Tags: python

I am confused on how the split function is working in this bit of code. "i.split(":")[1][1:-1]

I know [1] is accessing the index of the split list, but I am not sure what [1][1:-1] together does.

For reference, here is the code I am working with:

```
data = '    All User Profile     : United_Wi-Fi\r', '    All User Profile     : Free Airport WIFI\r', ' 

profiles = [i.split(":")[1][1:-1] for i in data if "All User Profile" in i]
```

I get a neat and formatted list if I output this data after splitting it. But I just don't know what the indexes are referencing.

Comment: The result of `split()` will be a string. You can slice strings with `"some string"[1:-1]` which will cut the first and last characters.  So first you index the second element of the list from `split()` then you are indexing a string. It seems like `i.split(":")[1].strip()` might be clearer.

Comment: Do you understand what `"hi mom"[1:-1]` does? (can you predict the result before testing it?) `x[y][z]` is just taking `x[y]`, and then applying `[z]` to that result. There is nothing tricky about it.

Comment: Another good way to go about understanding code is to *try it*; and then make small changes, try to predict the effect of the change, and test your prediction.